# How to float icons over an existing div using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have an existing div. I would like to add some little image icons(like a question mark png icon) over this div but I will float it directly above the div corners (but still inside the div territory) in either of the following positions:

Top-right
Top-left
Bottom-left
Bottom-right

One condition is that it will never alter the existing div(no change in layout, margin, style, etc). The icons would simply float over them.    I am attempting to use using padding-left attribute to the image but it ruins the layout of the existing div. I would like to look them unchanged even with the icons floating over them.
   Is there a simple way of doing this with jQuery or CSS?

Thank you for sharing the tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

***HTML***

```
<div class="target" style="position:relative;height:200px;width:200px;background: #ccc;margin: 25px">
    Target div
</div>
```

***jQuery***

```
$('.target').append('<img src="http://www3.emersonprocess.com/rosemount/wirelessestimator/App_Themes/Basic/images/questionmark_icon.gif" style="position:absolute; top: -20px; right: -12px">');​
```

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rAF3r/1/)***

​

Comment: Thank you, I really like this example.. This is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

To make what you want, you can just use CSS. Assuming your 4 s are in the div, you can do it in 2 ways:

- put a CSS style position: relative on the DIV, and position: absolute on each . Then, for each , you can use CSS position rules like **top, bottom, left, right** to place your  element

example:

```
<div style="position: relative; width: 100px; height: 100px">
    <img src="your_file" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: 10px; height: 10px;">
    ....other <img> with different position...
</div>
```

- use the float CSS attribut (**left, right**) on your s to put them on each corner of the .